# How to inject a JobScheduler on a micronaut controller?

Tags: kotlin, micronaut, jobrunr

I'm trying to `@Inject` a `JobScheduler` from `jobrunr` into my micronaut `@Controller` but I'm getting this error:

> Internal Server Error: Failed to inject value for parameter [jobScheduler] of class: com.myapp.http.controllers.MyController\n\nMessage: No bean of type [org.jobrunr.scheduling.JobScheduler] exists. Make sure the bean is not disabled by bean requirements (enable trace logging for 'io.micronaut.context.condition' to check) and if the bean is enabled then ensure the class is declared a bean and annotation processing is enabled (for Java and Kotlin the 'micronaut-inject-java' dependency should be configured as an annotation processor).\nPath Taken: new ReturnController(JobScheduler jobScheduler) --> new ReturnController([JobScheduler jobScheduler])

I've installed `micronaut-inject-java`, `org.jobrunr:jobrunr-micronaut-feature:5.2.0` and my controller look like this:

```
@Controller("/return")
class MyController(private val jobScheduler: JobScheduler) {

    @Post
    fun create() = jobScheduler.schedule(Instant.now()) { println("scheduled...") }
}
```

On my `application.yml` I've also configured the datasource:

```
datasources:
  default:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
    driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver
    username: postgres
    password: postgres
    dialect: POSTGRES
```

How can I inject `JobScheduler` into my controller?

Comment: "How can I inject JobScheduler into my controller?" - It isn't Kotlin, but there is a Java example at https://github.com/jobrunr/example-micronaut/blob/9e8d41883641f449c03b25107a482214d9926c2b/src/main/java/org/jobrunr/examples/webapp/api/JobController.java#L23-L24.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the project at [github.com/jeffbrown/injectjobscheduler](https://github.com/jeffbrown/injectjobscheduler).

[src/main/kotlin/com/example/MyController.kt](https://github.com/jeffbrown/injectjobscheduler/blob/ae32a7c34f98cf9d8b9b7d5071b72d78fbea166f/src/main/kotlin/com/example/MyController.kt)

```
package com.example

import io.micronaut.http.MediaType
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Controller
import io.micronaut.http.annotation.Get
import org.jobrunr.scheduling.JobScheduler

@Controller("/return")
class MyController(private val jobScheduler: JobScheduler) {

    @Get(produces = [MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN])
    fun index(): String {
        return jobScheduler.javaClass.name
    }
}
```

It may be that you have not enabled the scheduler.  See [src/main/resources/application.yml#L8-L11](https://github.com/jeffbrown/injectjobscheduler/blob/ae32a7c34f98cf9d8b9b7d5071b72d78fbea166f/src/main/resources/application.yml#L8-L11):

```
---
jobrunr:
  job-scheduler:
    enabled: true
```

Comment: FYI... The `jobrunr` changes are all in the commit at https://github.com/jeffbrown/injectjobscheduler/commit/ae32a7c34f98cf9d8b9b7d5071b72d78fbea166f.